# How can i make LINQ Query to get Category wise data from subCategory id

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-web-api

[image]

I have the EDMX model. I have three tables: `CostType`, `SubCostType` and `ProjectCost`.
`SubCostType` has relation with `CostType` and `ProjectCost` has relation with `SubCostType`. Can't i get `CostType` wise data from `ProjectCost` table from the relation?
( i added a extra relation with `CostType` and  `ProjectCost` Should i do it? )
On `ProjectCost` table if i store `SubCostType` with others information then how can i get data with `CostType` wise? Is my current relation ok with extra relation?
Is there any need junction table? How can i make LINQ query to get my desired result?
I have only `CostTypeID` from user then i should show him all data related to this `CostTypeID`. But in the `ProjectCost` table i have only `SubCostTypeID`

====================================My Expected Result====================
User select CostType id from Dropdown list then i have to show them all ProjectCost data related to that CostType. But in ProjectCost table i have only SubCostTypeID.

Comment: Can you give an example of expected query result?

Comment: I edited my ques with expected result. @Sami

Comment: But your `ProjectCost` model seems to have a reference to `CostTypeID`. Doesn't it work or why can't you use that? Or did I misunderstand the question..

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add an extra relation to `CostType` from `ProjectCost` with column named `CostType`. If I understand correctly, you have a Project; Project refers `ProjectCost`; `ProjectCost` refers `SubCostType` and `SubCostType` has `CostType`. Therefore you can access `CostType` from `SubCostType` with column SubCostType and the column `CostType` in table `ProjectCost` is unnecessary.

Came to your question, you can select it with this query;

```
var result = (from projectCost in db.ProjectCost 
              join subCostType in db.SubCostType on projectCost.SubCostType equals subCostType.SubCostTypeId
              join costType in db.CostType on subCostType.CostType equals costType.CostTypeId
              where costType.CostTypeId == selectedCostTypeId  
              select projectCost );
```

Comment: No. You didn't understand. Project refers ProjectCost; ProjectCost refers SubCostType and SubCostType has a CostType. On the image i made a extra relation with CostType as don;t get CostType wise data without the extra relation.

Comment: @Fawel ok, now I understand and edited the relation between them. Is it correct now?

Comment: Great! It works! It was simple but I though it complex way.

Comment: @Fawel so now you can tag it as the answer.